# Shaders are always showed with fixed values in material editor? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to get a value property from a `shader` attached in an object at runtime, but it's never changes in material editor. Maybe I misunderstood anything of how shaders works?

I read about the `GetFloat`, `GetColor`, etc but don't figure out yet how it properly works to get an information of a `shader` in `Update()`. The real objective here is catch a specific value from `shader` (in realtime) and do something in C# script, if it's possible.

**C# example:**

```
public Color colorInfo;

Awake()
{
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();// Get renderer
    rend.material.shader = Shader.Find("Unlit/shadowCreatures");//shader
}

Update()// I want the info in a realtime
{
    //get current float state of the shader
    colorInfo = rend.material.GetColor("_Color"); 
    //If I setup a white color in shader properties, the color in material editor is always white
}
```

**Shader:**

```
Shader "Unlit/shadowCreatures"
{
Properties {
    _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    [PerRendererData]_MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Cutoff("Shadow alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
}
SubShader {
    Tags 
    { 
        "Queue"="Geometry"
        "RenderType"="TransparentCutout"
        "PreviewType"="Plane"
        "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
    }
    LOD 200

    Cull Off

    CGPROGRAM
    // Lambert lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
    #pragma surface surf Lambert addshadow fullforwardshadows

    // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    fixed4 _Color;
    fixed _Cutoff;

    struct Input
    {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
        fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        o.Alpha = c.a;
        clip(o.Alpha - _Cutoff);
        _Color = (0,0,0,0); //trying turn to black just for a test, and nothing happens
    }
    ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: *`but it's never changes in material editor`* You mean that you select your material in the editor, then run the game, and it doesn't change?

Comment: The material and the respective shader is already there. I was expected any change in the property value "_Color" here: https://imgur.com/30l1o7V

Comment: That's not what I asked, I asked "what is it that you have selected and are viewing in the inspector?"

Comment: Question solved. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out what you're trying to do and

## That's not how things work, sorry

Piecing together your comments and question, this is what I think you're trying to fiddle with:

```
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    _Color = (0,0,0,0); //trying turn to black just for a test, and nothing happens
}
```

That doesn't do what you think it does. That line sets *this* `_Color`:

```
#pragma target 3.0

sampler2D _MainTex;
fixed4 _Color;
fixed _Cutoff; //here
```

*Not* this one:

```
Properties {
    _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) //here
    [PerRendererData]_MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Cutoff("Shadow alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
}
```

That second one is what is shown in the inspector panel, and its linkage with the CGPROGRAM block is effectively one-way because `frag` `surf` and `geom` are all called multiple times, in parallel, and rely on receiving the same data in, so the `Properties` value is read into the CGPROGRAM and the CGPROGRAM's values are discarded when it is done.

I don't think there's *any* way you can make the shader CGPROGRAM do anything that you can read from C# (because that code runs hundreds of times per frame, how would you know *which one* to read from?)

I know you can get at the *properties* (including changing a property for *one* instance or for *all* instances), but not the underlying CGPROGRAM data. The only way I can even think of getting around this would be to render to a texture and then read the texture data, and that would be slow (and again, you get into "which pixel has the value you want"?)

Comment: I spent all day trying to understand that. All clarified now, thank you sir!

Comment: (And yes, that was definitely what I expected)